# Suppressing the request when running PHPUnit with Kohana 3.2

Tags: phpunit, kohana-3.2

I'm having trouble correctly setting up unit testing in Kohana 3.2.

I installed PHPUnit.  I changed the bootstrap to activate Kohana's unittest module.  I also changed the index.php file to look like this:

```
if ( ! defined('SUPPRESS_REQUEST'))
{
    echo Request::factory()
        ->execute()
        ->send_headers()
        ->body();
}
```

I created a folder tests in my application folder.  In it, I inserted a phpunit.xml file that looks like this:

```
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="../../index.php">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Kohana Tests">
        <directory>./</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I am having two problems (the first one is the one I really need an answer to):

1- When I go into tests from the command line and try running phpunit, it seems that SUPPRESS_REQUEST never gets set to true.  The Request is executed, and therefore no tests are run.  The only way I am able to run the tests successfully is to momentarily comment out the entire Request::factory() line in index.php.  Does anyone know how to get around this problem?  If I should be adding a define('SUPPRESS_REQUEST', true) somewhere, where should I do it?  I'm new to Kohana and PHPUnit.

2- PHPUnit complains that the variable REMOTE_ADDR is not set.

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in
/Users/**/Sites/root/application/bootstrap.php on line 76
```

This is actually not a huge problem for now as tests still seem to run in spite of this, but  I'm wondering if anyone knows if I should be setting this variable somewhere in specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modules/unittest there is a file called bootstrap.php which works perfectly well with phpunit.

My phpunit.xml which references that bootstrap is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="../../modules/unittest/bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Kohana Tests">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Also, for the REMOTE_ADDR problem, when phpunit is running the CLI version of PHP, which I don't think has access to a REMOTE_ADDR variable.  If you look at the bootstrap from unittest, it does not use http related globals.

I'm not sure why you have to run Request::factory code in your bootstrap.  On my vanilla 3.2 install, the Request::factory code lives in index.php and not bootstrap.php and does not have any reference to SUPRESS REQUEST.  You may have some lingering files from a pre-3.2 installation which need cleaning.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, that was indeed the problem.  I was following a tutorial that had said to point to index.php (which is in fact where my Request::factory is - sorry if that wasn't clear).  Pointing it to the test bootstrap solved the problem!